# Mantener formato de fecha ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime

Tengo un modelo, el cual tiene un campo DateTime, por lo que utilizo DateType.Date para visualizar en las vistas el calendario. Mi problema es que el calendario se despliega con el formato correcto de fecha de acuerdo a mi zona (dd/MM/yyyy), pero el servidor en el cual subo la aplicación utiliza el formato MM/dd/yyyy, entonces da problemas ya que no reconoce al string que pone el calendario como un formato de fecha válido. Mi modelo actualmente se ve así

```
[Display(Name = "Fecha de nacimiento")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo requerido.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime FechaNacimiento
    {
        get { return fechaNacimiento; }
        set { fechaNacimiento = value; }
    }
```

También probé utilizando `DateTime.ParseExact(formCollection["fechaNacimiento"], "dd-MM-yyyy"` y sigue sin funcionarme.

Comment: Que calendario estas usando?

Comment: Te recomiendo que cambies el DatePicker a otro por ejemplo el de Jquery o Bootstrap. Tambien aqui puedes ver todos los [formatos de fecha aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings), cuando cambies el Datepicker asegurate de tener el mismo formato de fecha en el datepicker y en el modelo. yo tenia ese problema así lo solucione.

Comment: Gracias, pude solucionarlo como tu dices Starlin